# How to send a Label Print Job to a network CUPS/Raspberry Pi print server from a .NET Core Web API server docker container?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, printing, raspberry-pi

What I have currently completed:

- setup a Raspberry Pi with CUPS, plugged in a Dymo Labelwriter 450.
- Followed this link: [Setup Raspberry Pi](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi-print-server). This works and prints fine on my local machine (Windows), if i install the network printer through windows on my home network.
- Have printing jobs successfully print from .NET Core locally via the `System.Drawing.Printing`. This was mainly for testing. This is when the USB label printer is plugged directly into my machine.
- Have a .NET Core (3.1) Web API server running from a docker container. (Installed on an Ubuntu Server). FWIW it is a VueJs front end in a separate docker container.

In our facility (imagine it like a warehouse manufacturing facility) I would like to have a raspberry pi used as a "plug and play" printer server so we can move the Pi and the label printers around and the Pi will stay on the local network via Wifi. For now, these Raspberry Pi's will have a static IP address.

My dream goal, is to send a print job to the static ip of the CUPS server (the Raspberry Pi) without having to install the network printer within the docker container. For now i could store the IP address and configuration of the printer in the same database the server accesses.
I would also like it to be agnostic from the printer. So the only configuration or setup i need to worry about is installing the printer within CUPS.

I have currently researched:

- Printer Languages, like ZPL, EPL. This seems to no allow for printers to be agnostic.
- IPP (Internet Printing Protocol). This seems like a large learning curve and i cant find anything that uses .NET Core. Also not sure if this accomplishes the goal. (Any advice is appreciated)
- Some paid 3rd Party solutions: [Neodynamic libraries](https://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/aspnet-mvc/download/). But I am not sure if this will accomplish the goal, as it seems to utilize the list of Installed Printers.

I am trying to avoid installing printers within the docker container. As then it is not stateless and I will need to maintain this somehow. However, I am not totally opposed to compromising for this solution. However, it is outside my knowledge of docker and ubuntu/linux.

I would ultimately like everything to be contained in my .NET Core project/container. So if i have to send somethings to the CUPS server in a printer language, I am more willing to compromise with being married to a specific Printer brand/model, than installing a printer in the docker container. The print jobs are required to be sent from the Server (not the front end web client) as there are checks and verification's done with the database before printing.

The other, less desired, solution is to just plug the label printer into the physical server machine, and somehow share the USB port of the machine with the Docker container to send print jobs too. However, this is currently above my head for docker experience. Also it is physically restricting within the facility.

Is there a way to install printers programmatically? (i doubt this option is possible)

- as that would allow me to control the printers from my code through configuration or hard-coded values.

What is the best way to send a print job to a Raspberry Pi CUPS server, over a local network, without installing the printer on your machine (i.e. the docker container)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that lands here. This was my current solution:

- i first tried to get the docker container to utilize the USB port. I had this label printer plugged into the server, and was able to share the USB port with the `--priviledged` flag on the `docker run` command. I struggled to actually get the printer "installed" on the running docker container without switching its base image. So I scrapped this idea. I didnt like this idea as I was forced to leave the printer next to the server rack.

I was able to get the .NET Core Server to print, by utilizing `ipptool`

- I had to add some installation steps to my Dockerfile to give my image the ability to use ipptool. I included some extra/superfluous libraries as some helped me debug from within the container. i did all the extra work in a `/setup` folder as to not add to my main application
- **UPDATE**: Dymo irritatingly changed the server for the drivers that are in the `wget` line in the Dockerfile. I ended up having to download the driver file into my Solution/Project and then copy it.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
#install printer
WORKDIR /setup
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl cups cups-client printer-driver-dymo wget nano systemd usbutils netcat libgdiplus iputils-ping
# THIS IS OLD VERSION : RUN wget http://download.dymo.com/dymo/Software/Download%20Drivers/Linux/Download/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.tar.gz
COPY ["MyMainProjectFolder/Properties/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.tar.gz", "dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.tar.gz"]
RUN tar -xzf dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.tar.gz
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/cups/model
RUN cp /setup/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5/ppd/lw450.ppd /usr/share/cups/model/
RUN cp /usr/share/cups/cupsd.conf.default /etc/cups/cupsd.conf #https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/cups-service-stopped-um-18-04/17381
```

I was then able to call /bin/bash from within .net core. I also utilized the ShellHelper [Reference](https://loune.net/2017/06/running-shell-bash-commands-in-net-core/):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
    public static class ShellHelper
    {
        public static string Bash(this string cmd)
        {
            var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
            
            var process = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "/bin/bash",
                    Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
            };
            process.Start();
            string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I save the label images to a folder. I then just sent my label images with ipptool command.

```
//set whatever ip
var cmd = $"ipptool -vt -f {filepath} ipp://192.168.XXX.XXX:631/printers/DYMO_LabelWriter_450 printjob.ipp";

var result= cmd.Bash();
```

the contents of printjob.ipp

```
{
 OPERATION Print-Job
 GROUP operation-attributes-tag
  ATTR charset attributes-charset utf-8
  ATTR language attributes-natural-language en
  ATTR uri printer-uri $uri
 FILE $filename
}
```

I am not super happy with this solution. It does not print labels incredibly fast, but it does work. I am hoping to try to implement an ipp solution in .NET in the future, so I dont have to save to file and run shell commands.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, so I'm happy that someone already solved it. My case is, that I want to print labels that are stored on a MS SQL Reporting Server, so I wonder if it's possible to start the print job with the url as filepath. Another question is, if "var result= cmd.Bash();" delivers a status code whether the print succeeded?

Comment: I would assume using the URL as the filepath would work.. It is just a shell command, so it is easy to test. i dont parse the cmd.Bash() for any result as i am too lazy at this time and it doesnt matter too much. But when i was debugging you get the stdout or stderr text (if you add that). but CUPS doesnt send back a status code (i dont think).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Do me a lot! What I did here was to transform HTML into an image and then send the image for CUPS to print on the Raspberry. It looks great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some informations about this topic. Perhaps it can help?

https://www.alecburton.co.uk/2017/printing-from-a-docker-container/

Comment: This was one of the sites i came across. didnt exactly suit my needs but it did help